# Product ID to be encrypted

Tags: codeigniter, encryption, uri

I have an e-commerce site, created on Codeigniter. It has products and it's descriptions. The URL for description is : http://localhost/online_ups/products/product-details/26. Now, I want this URL id (26) to be encrypted in the URL and still work the same as it is working now.

I have no idea of implementing this functionality. Can someone help regarding the same?

The controller name is Product and the Model name is Productsdisplay.

Comment: i don't know if encryption is the right word... you could do something like throw a GUID onto your model and lookup by that.  Even doing something like hashing the ID won't really be great, since if someone knows what you're hashing they can just use the same hashing scheme against numbers to find the correct URLs.  What is it you're trying to do?

Comment: The answer is don't encrypt. [Read this for an explanation of why not.](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/09/comprehensive-guide-url-parameter-encryption-in-php)

Comment: Will keep that in mind buddies.Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

URL for description is : http://localhost/online_ups/products/product-details/26.

For that url you can do like below.

```
$product_id = urlencode(base64_encode(26));

$url = 'http://localhost/online_ups/products/product-details/'.$product_id;
```

And then in controller you can retrieve the id by below way.

```
function product-details ($product_id) {

     $product_id = base64_decode(urldecode($product_id));
     // you can get actual product id

}
```

Comment: Thanks, Sir. TecJ. It worked for me. I appreciate your help.